# How to import SVG file to use in image path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, react-google-maps

I'm importing a PNG image and passing it to an external component (@react-google-maps) to use as an icon. PNG import works fine, but the SVG file does not.

I've never worked with SVGs before so I must be misunderstanding something.

Might I be handling

```
import testSVG from './assets/m3.svg'
```

incorrectly?

You can see in my example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/usegooglemap-repro-4iqy3) that under map2:67 using testPNG works but testSVG does not.

This is where @react-google-maps plugs the path into an `<img>` tag:

```
img = "<img src='" + this.url + "' style='position: absolute; top: " + spriteV + "px; left: " + spriteH + "px; "

      //@ts-ignore
      if (!this.cluster.getClusterer().enableRetinaIcons) {
        img += "clip: rect(" + (-1 * spriteV) + "px, " + ((-1 * spriteH) + this.width) + "px, " +
          ((-1 * spriteV) + this.height) + "px, " + (-1 * spriteH) + "px);"
      }

      msg += "'>"
```

However, I don't believe that is causing an issue, because non-local SVG files work just fine.